# Next.js with Redux and Firebase authentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

I am working with Next.js with Redux and I want to integrate Firebase Authentication but I am confused about how the server will return the authenticated user's specefic data managed with Redux without having a conflict with another user's data.

The process is not clear for me.

Is there any working example which combine Next.js, Redux and Firebase authentication.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the `examples` folder at GitHub? Maybe you can find something to start